# getting an IBOutlet from another class swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a IBOutlet in a class Main_Screen which is avaliable in a class hooked up to a main ViewController which has a ScrollView but if i try to get it returns nil

code in View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollVieww: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

      self.scrollVieww.pagingEnabled = true
      self.scrollVieww.delegate = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScreen") as? Main_Screen {
            // imageview returns nil :(
            let imageView = vc.avatarImageView
        }

      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let V1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeScreen") as UIViewController!
        //Add initialized view to main view and its scroll view and also set bounds
        self.addChildViewController(V1)
        self.scrollVieww.addSubview(V1.view)
        V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        V1.view.frame = scrollVieww.bounds

        //Initialize using Unique ID for the View
        let V2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScreen") as UIViewController!
        //Add initialized view to main view and its scroll view also set bounds
        self.addChildViewController(V2)
        self.scrollVieww.addSubview(V2.view)
        V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        V2.view.frame = scrollVieww.bounds

        //Create frame for the view and define its urigin point with respect to View 1
        var V2Frame: CGRect = V2.view.frame
        V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        V2.view.frame = V2Frame

      //The width is set here as we are dealing with Horizontal Scroll
        //The Width is x3 as there are 3 sub views in all
        self.scrollVieww.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.width) * 2, (self.view.frame.height))

 }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you do anything with `vc`. Did you mean to add it to the scrollview?  When you allocate a second MainScreen later, (v2) it will be a different instance, so imageView won't be set and nowhere do you access `main_screen`

Comment: i want to call a UiScrollView delegate method and animate an imageView which i cant do in the class Main_Screen @Paulw11

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Don't do that. You should treat another view controller's views as private.

If you need to manipulate another view controller's UI, add public methods that you use to request the UI change, and then have code inside the VC make the change.

This is both much better design, and it avoids cases where the other view controller's views haven't been created yet, so they're nil and it fails/crashes with an "encountered nil when trying to unwrap optional" message.